# Query Single Item and convert to Model using Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

I am querying a single column from my database using Dapper. The Column content is a Json String. I want to desterilize it straightaway. And my code looks like this

```
string sql =@"SELECT [col1] FROM [table] where col3=@col3"
var data= await _connection.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<mymodelclass>(sql, parameters);
```

All looks good to me but this gives only empty object.
My modelclass structure

```
public  class mymodelclass
{
    public string LevelTwo { get; set; }
    public string LevelThree { get; set; }
    public string LevelFour { get; set; }
    public string LevelFive { get; set; }
}
```

Col1 content

```
{
    "LevelTwo": "05 Planning, Budgeting and Forecasting",
    "LevelThree": "5A Planning, Budgeting and Forecasting",
    "LevelFour": "5A.07 Prepare Forecasts, Finalize Presentations / Reports",
    "LevelFive": "zxczx",
}
```

Comment: please provide `mymodelclass` structure and example of `[col1]` content

Comment: and there(in db) is present correct record for your parameters?

Comment: Col1 has json value in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dapper doesn't perform JSON deserialization, so: query the data as a `string` (via `var json = connection.QuerySingle<string>(query, args);` or similar), then run that `string` through your choice of JSON deserializer - `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<mymodelclass>(json)` or similar.